# Javascript class instanceof

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, class, vite

Tengo una app en node.js con typescript y express.js y tratando de manejar los errores me encontre con este problema y no puedo entender bien porque pasa y como llegar al resultado esperado.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}

const err = new CustomError('unauth');

console.log(err instanceof CustomError);
```

No entiendo porque devuelve 'true' en una app react con vite.js y 'false' en una app node.js. Y como puedo checkear si el objeto 'err' fue creado con la class 'CustomError'

Comment: No puedo replicar tu error, siempre me da true, no tenes un repo a la app?

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta que en node.js de seguro estas utilizando CommonJS para importar la instancia de CustomError y como lo tienes creado puede no ser la misma que la instancia creada en otro módulo y es allí donde la verificación de instanceof falla.

Pudieras solucionar este problema, exportando e importando la clase CustomError en lugar de crear una nueva instancia directamente en cada archivo

entonces tú "customError.ts" sería asi:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}

export default CustomError;
```

y en archivo que lo necesites sería:

```
import CustomError from './customError';

const err = new CustomError('unauth');

console.log(err instanceof CustomError);
```

Si en los dos entornos lo importas de esta manera no vas a tener problemas.

Comment: Probé importando el fichero como me comentas, pero me sigue devolviendo un 'false'. Estoy compilando con 'ts-node' node v18.14.0